# Add a .exe file icon to launcher

Tags: launcher, unity-dash, lock

[image]I have 2 or 3 programs that are not installed, just extracted. 
These extractions mostly have an .exe file.. for example repetier host.

the files are deep in a tree in my pc, i have been able to add them to my dash but would like them them in the Launcher.

the normal "lock to launcher" doesn't work, also i have not been able to drag and drop from the dash.

is there a solution for this?  and ifso.. how?

Comment: Linux can't run EXEs

Comment: Apparently it does. Well i have done so, so it must. 
I admitt i was amazed myself but still, they run and run stable.... also that was not the question.  If i found that it wouldn't run i would not have asked the question on how to make a short cut to the launcher.

Comment: the .exe files are run using `wine` not by Linux itself. Nautilus has set "open with" to wine, so that you can double click them. You must imitate that behaviour with a command like `wine start /Unix "/path/to/file.exe"` in a .Desktop file

Comment: Can you add anything to your launcher from dash?  I have no trouble adding  wine...exe icons to the launcher from either dash or even just dragging an icon from the desktop.

Comment: yeah no problems there... but i believe RoVo's answer below to solve the issue. i will try later on. in any case many thanks to all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Executables (.exe) files can be run on Linux using [wine](https://www.winehq.org/), a windows emulator software. Nautilus has probably set "open with"-setting for .exe files to use wine, so that you can double click them. The dash has probably the same feature.

For it to work similar from the launcher, you must imitate that behaviour with a command like `wine start /Unix "/path/to/file.exe"` in a `.Desktop` file

---

Create a .dektop file in `~/.local/share/applications` with following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=Run Name of your Program
Terminal=false
Name=Name of your Program
Exec=wine start /Unix "/path/to/file.exe"
Type=Application
Icon=/path/to/logo.png
```

Of course replace the necessary bits.

---

**Alternative**:

Install `alacarte` and do the same with a simple GUI.

```
sudo apt-get install alacarte
```

---

Now you should be able to see that entry in the dash (maybe you need to refresh the dash one or two times). You can then copy-paste it to the Launcher.